# URL amigável com apontamento no htaccess

Tags: regex, htaccess, url-amigável

Meu site está em uma subpasta, quero que o caminho funcione independente do que eu inserir no nome da mesma, por exemplo:

www.meudominio.com.br/qualquer-coisa/index.php

www.meudominio.com.br/qualquer-coisa1/index.php

www.meudominio.com.br/qualquer-coisa2/index.php

www.meudominio.com.br/qualquer-coisa3/index.php

www.meudominio.com.br/qualquer-coisa4/index.php

www.meudominio.com.br/qualquer-coisa5/index.php

Onde está "qualquer-coisa" vai mudar varias vezes, deve funcionar como um Alias para a subpasta onde está o site, reconhecendo realmente qualquer coisa que for escrito ali.

Se eu inserir manualmente no script o nome que eu quero, já percebi que funciona, desta forma:

```
RewriteRule ^nome-que-eu-quero\/?(.*)$ /pasta_site/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Mas preciso que ele aceite tudo o que eu inserir antes do delimitador, tentei fazer assim:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/?(.*)$ /pasta_site/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Porém não funciona. O que estou fazendo de errado? Há algum método mais prático de fazer isso funcionar?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Pode colocar alguns exemplos de entrada e a saída desejada?

Comment: Fiz uma edição na pergunta e adicionei um exemplo da URL como tem que funcionar.

Comment: Deve retornar www.meudominio.com.br/pasta_site/index.php, sabendo-se que "pasta_site" é a pasta real onde se encontra o site.

Comment: Já tentei desta forma, não obtive sucesso. Existe algum trecho de código que deve ser citado antes desse?

Comment: Estou citando apenas RewriteEngine On, em seguida o código.

Comment: não consigo ver onde está errando, a regex que postei nos comentarios funciona, veja só https://regex101.com/r/y3Y7kr/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com a captura negada `[^ ]`.

```
RewriteRule ^\/?[^\/]*(\/(.*))?$ /pasta_do_site/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Seja funcionando em [REGEX101.](https://regex101.com/r/rjZ2QY/1)

#### Explicação

- `\/?[^\/]*` - captura do "qualquer_coisa" que deve terminar na `/`
- `(\/(.*))?` - Se houver uma `/` captura o que vier apos ela, gerando o grupo 2.

Comment: Boa resposta. Apenas um detalhe: não precisa escapar as `/`, nem o `$` no final.